# How to get the id value of which child div is clicked of any parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose I have a parent `div` which contains two more div which are created dynamically using jQuery. When I click on div one then it will alert or console its id value if I clicked on the second div then it will show the second div id attribute value

```js
for (i=0; i < 3; i++){
       content = "<div class='dataToAppend' id="+i+" style='cursor:pointer; margin:30px; display:inline-block;'>"
       content += '<img id='+i+' src='+i+' >'               
       content += "</div>"
       $(".data").append(content)
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data"></div>
```

In this snippet when I click on one image then I want it console its id attribute

Comment: I see no onclick event on anything of the sort in your code, please show us what you've already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`$(document).on('click', '.dataToAppend img', function() {}`

To add a click event to all your imgaes within the div with the class `.dataToAppend`.

Next, you can use `$(this).attr('id');` to get the `id` of the image you clicked on.

Also, I suggest you build up a string called `content` in your for loop (as `.append()` is a somewhat expensive method to run), and only once that is complete you `.append()` the `content` to your DOM. This way you are only adding to the DOM once, rather than multiple times.

See working example below:

```js
let content = "";
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  content += "<div class='dataToAppend' id=" + i + " style='cursor:pointer; margin:30px; display:inline-block;'>"
  content += '<img id=' + i + ' src=' + i + ' >'
  content += "</div>"
}
$(".data").append(content);

$(document).on('click', '.dataToAppend img', function() {
  let id = $(this).attr("id");
  console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can bind a [delegated click event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) to the images:

```js
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  content = "<div class='dataToAppend' id='div" + i + "' style='cursor:pointer; margin:30px; display:inline-block;'>"
  content += '<img id=' + i + ' src=' + i + ' >'
  content += "</div>"
  $(".data").append(content)
}

$(".data").on('click', 'img', function() { // use a delegated event on the image
  console.log(this.id); // this is the image id

  console.log($(this).parent().attr('id')); // this is the div id
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="data"></div>
```

Please note that ids should be unique and you currently have your div and image ids being created the same, I edited above so they are different

Comment: From the title I suppose he wants the id of the div, not the id of the image

Comment: Ah right, edited to get the div id too - I was going from the *In this snippet when I click on one image then I want it console its id attribute*

Answer (score 3):

Capture the click event in its bubbling phase on the `.test` element, check the event target, and,  if it's a `div` then get the `id` else if it's an image get the `id` of its `parentNode`.

You may use *vanillaJS* for this task

```
document.querySelector('.test').addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  let tgt = ev.target;
  if (tgt.matches('div')) {
    console.log(tgt.id);
  }
  if (tgt.matches('img')) {
    console.log(tgt.parentNode.id);
  }
});
```

(As a side note, your id can't start with a digit)

Answer (score 1):

With vanilla JavaScript, you can just query all three `.dataToAppend` divs after the for loop and use the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method to return the id of each element.

---

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of what I have described above:

```js
var data = document.querySelector(".data");

for (i=0; i < 3; i++){
       content = "<div class='dataToAppend' id=imgDiv"+i+" style='cursor:pointer; margin:30px; display:inline-block;'>";
       content += '<img id='+i+' src=img'+i+' >';            
       content += "</div>";
       data.innerHTML += content;
}

var dataDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".dataToAppend");

dataDivs.forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener("click", () => console.log(div.id));
});
```

```html
<div class="data"></div>
```

---

**N.B.** In the above example, I have appended a non-numeric character for easier element targeting in CSS.